# Android CheckedTextView wrong position

Tags: android, listview, checkedtextview

I trying click 
I'm trying to implement a list that uses state selectors.
But I have problems when using textView.setChecked (textView.isChecked ()!); .

The "isChecked" does not correctly

For example try to select the number 0 or penultimate position and the last is also selected, it is not normal.

I put an image.

The list got within a adapter, I think the adapter resets the positions of the items that are underneath, it's the only explanation I can find him.

[image]

In my ListActivity :

```
 setListAdapter(new ListMultiplesAdapter(this,R.layout.test12, values,listview));
        final ListView listView = getListView();
        listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
```

My adapter :

```
public ListMultiplesAdapter(Context mContext, int layoutResourceId, String[] data, ListView lv) {

    super(mContext, layoutResourceId, data);

    this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.data = data;
    this.lv = lv;
}

lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,long id) {
                SparseBooleanArray sparseBooleanArray = lv.getCheckedItemPositions();
                System.out.println("Clicked Position := "+position +" Value: "+sparseBooleanArray.get(position));

                CheckedTextView textView = (CheckedTextView)view.findViewById(R.id.check);
                textView.setChecked(!textView.isChecked());

            }
        });
```

Comment: For it, you'll have to save the position where you check the checkboxes.

Comment: You need to implement an adapter that does not re-create the items when they are scrolled off the screen.

Comment: yes, I am using a listview, How I can no recreate ? , I update my code "setListAdapter"

Comment: You must override implementation of  the getView method in your adapter class.

Comment: You must Create holder

Comment: I removed override but not work

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of an implementation of BaseAdapter.

```
public class DemoListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
...
...

 @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ListItem item = mList.get(position);
        ViewHolder holder;

        // If it is a new item, create it otherwise use the existing item previously created in
        // this method.
        if (convertView == null) {

            LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = li.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);

            holder = new ViewHolder();

            // This is where the text is originally set
            holder.mListItemText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_title);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        // use the existing data from the item that already exists
        holder.mListItemText.setText(item.getItemText());


        return convertView;
    }

private static class ViewHolder {
        public TextView mListItemText;

    }
...
...
}
```

Then when you scroll you can re-use the existing items in the list.

Comment: The problem is that I use "ArrayAdapter" second step will listview my "ListActivity". my code is fine, it works when the "lv.setOnItemClickListener" running on my ListActivity, but do not put it here, because the check does not work well, and in my adapter have this problem of checks

Comment: ArrayAdapter extends BaseAdapter. Just store a flag for checked/unchecked in your object.

Comment: think the problem is not mine if not CheckedTextView

Comment: You will need to attach an onClickListener to each view in the list. [Here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html) is a few tutorials they are a bit old now but still have very good examples of different scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should use custom listview [e.g.](https://www.caveofprogramming.com/guest-posts/custom-listview-with-imageview-and-textview-in-android.html) so you can customize your functionality of list adapter. you can refer android blogs for this.

you can use [SparceBooleanArray](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/SparseBooleanArray.html) to hold the checked item position and in `getView()` method use this data to check or uncheck items using position of adapter. in short you have to hold all the positions of checked as well as unchecked items in listview and also use viewholder to reuse views.